# String parsing via training examples

Tags: regex, parsing, bayesian, peg

I'm in a position where I need to write a very large number of parsing rules (in other words, a function that transforms a string into another string or structured data) and while I figured I would use PEG for this, it would be magnitudes easier or me to write by just providing a **list of example sentences and their correct parsings** and it seems technically trivial in my mind, but I'm confused.

I've played around with PEGjs (a parsing expression grammar tool) and regex. It seems that for my purposes the needs are really very basic, much less than all the power provided by PEGs and regex.

**Here's an example of what I would like to parse:**

```
"I want a red square" -> "make a red square"
"Give me a red square!" -> "make a red square"
"If you please, sir, a blue triangle." -> "make a blue triangle"
"Scratch that." -> "delete last shape"
```

As you can see, I want to provide hundreds of example sentences each paired with a correct parsing, and let the computer write the functions necessary parse all sentences that follow the pattern.

It's a bit hard to get my head around this, so I'm asking all hackers:

1. Isn't it true that if I just provide lots of different variations of my input sentences, only very simple logic would be required (i.e. no machine learning, no PEG, and no regex)?
2. Could some machine learning facility (Bayesian?) make this an easy task? (In my application I DO NOT need 100% certainty for parsing sentences; ambiguity is ok, especially if I can present that ambiguity for the user to resolve)
3. What are some tools (libraries) or logic (pseudocode, please!) that are well-suited to this kind of problem, or just illustrate its nature?

Comment: Is your domain limited to geometry with a concrete combination of noun substantives and a finite set of transformative verbs, as per your examples?

Answer (score 0):

I think the scope of this discussion may be a little over my head, as I don't know much about machine learning, but have you considered simplifying your problem and just coming up with a list of simple rules, then translating them literally into code?

I would search for code words like "blue," "triangle," "scratch," etc. and use conditional logic to have your program do the right thing. Something like this pseudocode:

```
words = split input

if words contains "scratch", "delete", "never mind", etc.:
  delete last shape; exit

if words contains
  "red": color = :red
  "blue": color = :blue
  "triangle": shape = :triangle
  "square": shape = :square

if shape is undefined and color == :red
  error "red what?"; exit

if shape is undefined and color == :blue
  error "blue what?"; exit

if color is undefined and shape == :triangle
  error "what color triangle?"; exit

if color is undefined and shape == :square
  error "what color square?"; exit

if both color and shape are defined:
  add [color, shape] to shapes
```

If that seems excessively verbose (especially if you plan on adding a large quantity of colors and shapes), you might consider using metaprogramming to have your program write all the rules algorithmically. A language like Clojure or Ruby would excel at this kind of thing.

The key point is that your AI doesn't necessarily need to understand English grammar; it just needs to be able to find key words using regular expressions, which is a trivial task.

You might also consider looking into learning Prolog -- it's an ideal language if you want to take a declarative programming approach, which is exactly what you're describing. The idea is that instead of writing all of the implementation details yourself, you essentially write a bunch of sample cases and their expected outcomes, and the Prolog compiler deduces how to handle other cases. (Disclaimer: I have almost zero experience with Prolog, but I learned a little about it by reading the book [*Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks).)